# Angular Material matBadge inside mat-menu on top of menu?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I'm trying to have a matBadge on a mat-menu-item inside mat-menu. The resulting badge is cropped by the menu's edges.

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXW8W.png)

This is my template:

```
    <mat-menu #mainMenu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item color="accent" [matBadge]="newControlMessages" *ngIf="showModeratorBoard" routerLink="helpdesk-control">
    Help Desk
  </button>
  <button mat-menu-item color="primary" *ngIf="isLoggedIn" routerLink="edit-user">
    Edit User
  </button>
  <button mat-menu-item color="accent" *ngIf="isLoggedIn" (click)="logout()">
    Logout
  </button>
</mat-menu>
```

I tried adding the following .css but had no results:

```
.mat-badge-active .mat-badge-content{
  all: revert;
  top: unset;
  right: unset;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```